# Square App API (Scheduling)

Tags: square-connect

Currently does the Square App API include SquareUp's scheduling service that they provide?

I have looked everywhere and have not manage to find anything about scheduling for the API

Comment: Why don't you just email their support and get an answer directly from the source? This isn't an actual programming question and is therefore off topic.

Answer (score 1):

There are no APIs for Square Appointments at this time.

Comment: Thanks. Going to email in a request for this.